# Profile-Guided Optimization (PGO) differences between Clang and Apple Clang

Tags: development

After reading the documentation for ([Apple Clang](https://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-23/clang/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html)) it's not clear, are there any PGO implementation differences between these compilers. Maybe some Apple-specific additions to PGO were implemented like integrations with other Apple developer tooling. It's important since we are going to use PGO in our pipelines, and we are choosing between these two compilers.